# How do I restrict a field in Cognito Forms to allow only digits?

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I restrict a field in Cognito Forms to allow only digits?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com). The best way to do this would be to use one of our fields that only allows numbers to be entered.

[image]

We offer several different fields to use when creating your form but some of the fields will only allow numbers as a valid input. Those fields are: Number, Currency, and Phone. The Phone number field will require you to have a phone number that is 10 digits long, and will auto format as such: XXX-XXX-XXXX. The Currency option will also default to USD currency placing the dollar sign($) before the number and adding a decimal to the number if none is provided. (0.00).

If you are looking to only collect digits then I would use the Number field. This will require users who are filling out your form to only input numbers into the field.